# Passing matlab data, giving back python networkX graph

Tags: python, matlab, networkx

I wonder if I could pass a matlab object to call a python graph visualization function with networkx, and get that graph by matlab command according to the passed object's data?

Let me say, I am in matlab environment, having an algorithm including different classes and objects in matlab, what I need is to make python objects from this;

```
class GridVisualization():

    def __init__(self, vector_of_matlab_objects):  
        ##vector_of_matlab_objects could be either a matlab matrix or a vector including matlab objects
        self.nodes = [vector_of_matlab_objects]
        self.configuration = dict()      
        self.import_libs()


    def import_libs(self):
        import networkx as nx
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    def initialize(self):
        ## basically it builds overall configuration of the graph, extracting necessary data from matlab matrix od vector of objects
        for n in self.nodes:
            self.configuration[n.local_name] = dict()
            self.configuration[n.local_name].update(weight=n.weight)
            self.configuration[n.local_name].update(heatmap=n.load_degree)
            self.configuration[n.local_name].update(has_edge_with=[i for i in n.connected_nodes])
            layer=n.layer
            self.configuration[n.local_name].update(layer=n.layer)
            self.configuration[n.local_name].update(position=(self.set_position(layer)))

    def set_position(self, layer):
        # some calculation and returns a tuple of position
        return (x,y)


    def draw_grid(self):
        ## once the data are passed, calling this function from matlab, we want to get graph appeared on the screen 
        G=nx.Graph(network = 'RadialGrid')
        for (key,value) in self.configuration.items():
            for v in value:
                G.add_edge(key, v, value['weight'])
            pos_dict = {key : value['position']}
            nodes = pos_dict.keys()
        warm=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] > 0.5]
        off=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight']==0]
        cold=[(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if 0.5>d['weight']>0]
        fit_nodes=nx.spring_layout(G, pos=pos_dict, fixed = nodes) 
        nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,fit_nodes,node_size=500)
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,fit_nodes,edgelist=warm,width=6,alpha=0.5,edge_color='r')
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,fit_nodes,edgelist=cold,width=3,alpha=0.5,edge_color='b')
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,fit_nodes,edgelist=off,width=5,alpha=0.5,edge_color='k',style='dashed')

        nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,fixed_nodes)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()
```

and then have my graph appeared on the screen, 
I  have no idea even it is possible or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem doing this? Do you know how to call python libraries from MATLAB?

Comment: Actually no, so far I just tried to use very basic feature of matlab engine for python, but for reverse direction, python library or objects from matlab, I'm not sure if I can.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-python-libraries.html

Comment: I need to use networkx weighted graph( or even something like it in matlab itself), from matlab. To build a grid visualization, where the networkx package seems to be the solution.

Comment: Then my previous comment should provide exactly the information you need.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, 
but one thing; I have my networkx object created, how to have it shown? What is the alternative of matplotlib in matlab?

Comment: I don't understand your question, you don't use matplotlib in matlab. Matplotlib is a python library replicating matlab functionality in python.

Comment: I mean in python running this ; 
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,fixed_nodes)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

the graph is shown, to do it from matlab what can I do?

Comment: Assuming that you only want to plot the graph, a quick-and-dirty solution would be to use `save('vector_of_matlab_objects.mat')` in Matlab and then load that `.mat` file in your python script with `scipy.io.loadmat`. Then, you could have a wrapper function in Matlab that does the `.mat` saving and calls your python script in the command prompt within Matlab with `system('python plottingscript.py' )`. Let me know if you have questions but my honest advice is to stick to one environment (preferably Python!).

Comment: Since I'm also looking for a simple solution, this quick-and-dirty approach, could be the right answer. By the way I guess you are absolutely right, I've been in trouble doing this simple process in two environment and now got the answer!
Thank you very much!